# Need Google Maps to open Multiple Marker Popups with Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am creating a Google map with multiple markers that I want to popup into a Fancybox lightbox when clicked on. I must admit, I am quite a novice at javascript and Google Maps API.

I have put some pieces of different sample scripts together and come up with something that actually works decently. I have the markers the way I want them (well, without captions... which I still have to figure out), the style of map the way I want it, and I even have the markers popping up lightboxes when clicked on.

However, all markers end up opening one URL in the lightbox. I guess that makes a bit of sense.  The Fancybox code is being distributed to all the markers, instead of each one individually. I tried to make another argument with a url and pass it into the Fancybox script, but it still just picks up the last marker's url and uses it for all the markers. How would I be able to get the URL to work for each marker instead of all the markers at once?

I did find a similar question on here:

[Multiple fancybox google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776970/multiple-fancybox-google-map)

However, it seams to use a different route of attacking the same issue. Plus, I can't seem to get their script to work by itself, let alone integrate it with my code. So, while I get how the solution works for them, it doesn't seem to help me.

My code is as follows:

```
var map;

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

function initialize() {

  var featureOpts = [
    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: '#CCCCCC' },
        { saturation: '-100' },     
        { visibility: 'simplified' },
        { gamma: 2 },
        { weight: .4 }
      ]
    },
    {
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [
        { visibility: 'off' }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'water',
      stylers: [
        { color: '#efefef' }
      ]
    }
  ];

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    scrollwheel: false,
    keyboardShortcuts: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0531553, -84.3615928),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
    },
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'Custom Style'
  };

  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);

 setMarkers(map, schools);
}


var schools = [
  ['Canton', 34.2352063, -84.4846274, 4, 'popup.htm'],
  ['Austell', 33.8158106, -84.6334938999999, 3, 'popup.htm'],
  ['Marietta', 33.9578674, -84.5532791, 2, 'popup.htm'],
  ['Atlanta', 33.7635085, -84.43030209999999, 1, 'popup2.htm']
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {

  var image = {
    url: 'images/fml-home.png',

    size: new google.maps.Size(67, 63),

    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),

    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 63)
  };
  var shadow = {
    url: 'images/fml-shadow.png',

    size: new google.maps.Size(45, 18),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 18)
  };

  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 67, 60, 67, 60 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var schools = locations[i];

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(schools[1], schools[2]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: schools[0],
        zIndex: schools[3]

    });

        var href = schools[4];

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

         $.fancybox({
    frameWidth    : 800,
    frameHeight   : 600,
    href : href,
    type : 'iframe'
        });
            });

}

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: I guess the issue is here `var href = schools[4];` ...I guess it should rather be `var href = schools[i][4];`

Comment: also `frameWidth` should be `width` and `frameHeight` should be `height` only

Comment: also change `title: schools[0]` by `title: schools[i][0]` and `zIndex: schools[3]` by `zIndex: schools[i][3]`

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. 

I had originally used width/height in there, but it didn't seem to have any affect on the lightbox.  So, I was just trying whatever I could. 

Also, I tried your other solution. The problem I'm having with inserting the `[i]` in between the `schools` and the `[#]` (which does seem to make sense) is that it not only doesn't fix the issue, it also breaks the markers to where only the first marker shows up.  The others disappear. Is there another way to use the `schools[i]` and then the add argument number in some other format?

Comment: `inserting the [i] in between the schools and the [#] (which does seem to make sense)`.... this is what does make sense to me : http://jsfiddle.net/S2mKE/ ... maybe the problem is that you are overriding the var `schools = locations[i];`

Comment: `var locations = schools[i];` would make more sense

Comment: yes, `var locations = schools[i]` definitively makes more sense http://jsfiddle.net/S2mKE/2/

Comment: Yes, that did it. I switched that out and I was able to add the `[i]` to every instance after I did that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
marker["href"] = schools[4];

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

     $.fancybox({
       frameWidth    : 800,
       frameHeight   : 600,
       href : this.href,
       type : 'iframe'
     });
});
```

Comment: Poof! That did it!  This saved a the rest of my hair being pulled out.  Thanks a bunch!